# Callback after __doPostBack()?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, postback, webforms

I am refreshing an UpdatePanel with Javscript by calling a method like so:

```
reloadDropDown = function (newValue)
{
  __doPostBack("DropDown1", "");
  selectNewValueInDropDown(newValue);
}
```

Inside my UpdatePanel is a `<select>` box that I need to select an `<option>` with a **newValue**.  My problem is that my `selectNewValueInDropDown` method is being called prior to the `__doPostBack` from completing.  Is there a way I can "wait" for the postback before calling my `selectNewValueInDropDown` method?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To make my comment more concrete, here's the idea:

```
reloadDropDown = function (newValue)
{
    var requestManager = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
        // Here's where you get to run your code!
        selectNewValueInDropDown(newValue);

        requestManager.remove_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
    }
    requestManager.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

    __doPostBack("DropDown1", "");
}
```

Of course, you probably want to handle race conditions where two requests overlap. To handle that, you would need to keep track of which handler is for which request. You could use something like `ScriptManager.RegisterDataItem` on the server side, or call `args.get_panelsUpdated()` and check to see if the panel you're interested it was updated.

Answer (score 6):

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    //
}
function EndRequestHandler(sender, args)
{
    //request is done
}
```

Comment: But where would my parameter coming into play?  I also would need a single entry point method.

Comment: You will have to get crafty with JavaScript and set some state variables to know when to fire your method.  When you hijack the framework/process it's on you.

Comment: @BrianDavidBerman: You could write a function that calls `selectNewValueInDropDown(newValue)` then calls `Sys.WebForms...remove_endRequest(theFunction)` to remove itself as an event handler.

Comment: any idea why MS chose not to include a callback parameter in __doPostBack? is there a technical reason? or just oversight?