# Timing w/ ASP.NET AJAX TOOLKIT and JQUERY UI DIALOG

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am attempting to use the AJAX Toolkit on a project. I have previously just done jquery AJAX stuff. Its all fine, they each have their hurdles.

I have a page that has a list of items. DBL Clicking an item should show an edit form in an overlay.

I have this all largely working. The DBL Click invokes a function that does an _DoPostBack and then opens the dialog. My problem is simply timing. The DIALOG() function copies my DIV before it refreshes.

My approach is based on everything I have read to date. If there is a better way I have yet to stumble across, Id greatly appreciate a point in the right direction.

here I think are the important parts

The list is an userControl. It loads at page load. Each row has a dblclick  handler w/ the correct id. I find its easiest to create this server side.

The edit form is a user control in an update panel. The trigger is an ONSERVERCLICK event of an HTML BUTTON (this is how it was suggested i do it).

The first row i double click shows a dialogue w/ a blank form.
The second row I double click shows the dialog that I shoudl have seen w/ the first dbl clcik. 
And so on, and so on. 
I can make the div visible. THey are loading correctly. It just takes a short piece of time.

I think what I need is a way to pass a callback to __doPostBack so I can open the dialog when the load is complete. 
I have played w/ a JS sleep function and using timers, that's not the right way to go.

**My Question is**
a) is there some good example of using ajax toolkit to do something like this. i have looked. Combining jquery.ajax seems to bring a separate set of problems rendering controls that require script manager. Id rather stick w/ ATK if possible. (if there are good examples, id be happy to read them)

b) is there a way to act when __DoPostBack finishes. this seems the simplest way to finish what i am trying to do. Is there a separate approach I should be using?

this is the js function that responds to row.dblClick

```
function showRouteDetails(id) {

        var opts = {
            title: "Route Details",
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            buttons: [
               {
                   text: "OK",
                   click: function () { $(this).dialog("close"); }
               },
               {
                   text: "cancel",
                   click: function () { alert('cancel'); }
               }

            ]
        }


        'call the postback to refresh the user control w/ the correct data
        __doPostBack("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$btnLoadRoute", String(id));

        'show the dialog.  the named div surrounds the RouteEdit user control
         'the first time i dbl click, its blank. The second time, it shows the 
         'first route.... its just happening too early
        var div = $("#PutRouteHere");
        div.dialog(opts);
        div.dialog('open');


        beep();
    }
```

im happy to post any other pieces if someone wants to see them

tyia 
greg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the `AjaxControlToolkit`, I'd suggest the way I successfully use without the `jQuery UI Dialog`.

I use a [Modal Popup](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ModalPopup/ModalPopup.aspx) targeting a Panel with an UpdatePanel (inside you have your editing form). At DBL click, you fire a server event updating the UpdatePanel content and finally show the Modal Popup.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks, this wasnt exactly what i was looking for, but i did not know about that website. will probably help me going forward. I will look at the atk modal, it may solve my problem by staying 'in framework'

Comment: kc   my list and my edit form are both user controls. I would like to key off an image button (1 per row) in the list. where would you put the pupupextender? do you know of an example?

Comment: @greg I'd use one "PopupExtender" only. So you'd better place it where you place your user controls (not one for each row!).

Comment: right, my question was not clear. I was struggling with whether to put the popupextender in the host page, or in the list user control. I have done a lot of playing around in the past couple days. The host page really now just hosts the list usercontrol. The list usercontrol has the edit user control and the modal popup extender.  Not only does this make everything easier, it is also the right way to go for the sake of reuse.  thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

so right after you post a question, you always think of a new way to google it...

[Callback after __doPostBack()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7615691/callback-after-dopostback)

this posting does a great job of addressing the question exactly.